# Pointer to a new node in a Binary Tree

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I was solving problem of **insertion of node** in a binary tree. I have the following doubts:

1) If we are inserting a node then we should return a pointer pointing to that node as then only we will be able to access the node, right?

2) Then here why are we returning root? We must return `root->left` or `root->right` accordingly, where am I wrong?

```
struct node* insert(struct node* root, int data)
    {
        if (root == NULL)    //If the tree is empty, return a new,single node
            return newNode(data);
        else
        {
            //Otherwise, recur down the tree 
            if (data <= root->data)
                root->left  = insert(root->left, data);
            else
                root->right = insert(root->right, data);
            return root;
        }
    }
```

3) Is this root which the above code returns the changed one from what it was previously due to recursion?

Comment: Try drawing the algorithm out on paper and remembering to add recursive calls to a stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand the return value.

The return value of this `insert` function is a pointer to the subtree that now has `data` inserted into it.  If the passed in `root` was null, this is a new 1 node tree; if the passed in `root` is non-null, the return value is the same `root`.

This makes the recursion a bit simpler.  We simply recurse until we run head-on into `nullptr` in a branch.  Then the recursion stops, and the return value sets the parent's `left` or `right` node.

To create a brand new tree you type:

```
node* new_tree = insert(nullptr, 7);
```

to insert something into an existing tree you type:

```
existing_tree = insert(existing_tree, 7);
```

or equivalently

```
insert(existing_tree, 7);
```

so long as `existing_tree` isn't null.

This "double use" of the function (to both create and modify a tree) can confuse, but it makes the specific recursive use a tad less verbose, and makes the "empty tree is a nullptr" and "always do `existing_tree = insert(existing_tree, val);`" is a rule that makes the empty tree as the null tree work.

This is, however, a very C way of doing things.

A more [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) way of doing things would be:

```
std::unique_ptr<node> insert(std::unique_ptr<node> root, int data)
{
    if (root == nullptr)    //If the tree is empty, return a new,single node
        return std::make_unique<node>(data);
    else
    {
        //Otherwise, recur down the tree 
        if (data <= root->data)
            root->left  = insert(std::move(root->left), data);
        else
            root->right = insert(std::move(root->right), data);
        return std::move(root);
    }
}
```

where the flow of data into and out of the function is more explicit, and we assume `node` has a constructor that takes `data`.

Answer (score 0):

This recursive insert should always return the very root node of the tree. Just because you read `return root` doesn't mean the original function call has finished executing, it just means the n'th recursion has finished. The recursive calls have all been pushed onto the stack and therefore must all be resolved before the original caller receives the returned value.

You can get back to the inserted node by doing a `find` for the inserted value.